Issues using appleboy/ssh-action@1.03 trying to deploy to server
I am Dockerizing a Node app uploading it to Docker Hub and want to deploy it on my Hetzner server (which uses only IPv6 connection).
The part that I have issues with is SSH-ing to the server through GitHub Actions and running the docker stop, pull and start.
Here is the action I use:
    appleboy/ssh-action@v1.0.3
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.HETZNER_HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.HETZNER_USERNAME }}
          key: ${{ secrets.HETZNER_SSH_KEY }}
          port: 22
          protocol: tcp6
          debug: true
          script: |
            sudo docker login -u ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }} -p ${{ secrets.DOCKER_TOKEN }}
            sudo docker pull ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}/${{ secrets.DOCKER_IMAGE }}:latest
            sudo docker stop main  true
            sudo docker rm main  true
            sudo docker run -d --name main -p 8080:3000 ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}/${{ secrets.DOCKER_IMAGE }}:latest

What happens now is I get an error:
Warning: Unexpected input(s) 'protocol', valid inputs are ['entryPoint', 'args', 'host', 'port', 'passphrase', 'username', 'password', 'sync', 'use_insecure_cipher', 'cipher', 'timeout', 'command_timeout', 'key', 'key_path', 'fingerprint', 'proxy_host', 'proxy_port', 'proxy_username', 'proxy_password', 'proxy_passphrase', 'proxy_timeout', 'proxy_key', 'proxy_key_path', 'proxy_fingerprint', 'proxy_cipher', 'proxy_use_insecure_cipher', 'script', 'script_stop', 'envs', 'envs_format', 'debug', 'allenvs', 'request_pty']
Run appleboy/ssh-action@v1.0.3

Which makes 0 sense to me, since protocol is one of inputs on this version.
So am I doing anything wrong, I am also open to some kind of different way without using the appleboy action.

Where under https://github.com/appleboy/ssh-action/blob/029f5b4aeeeb58fdfe1410a5d17f967dacf36262/action.yml#L4 is protocol?

https://github.com/appleboy/ssh-action/blob/master/action.yml, here also in the readme of the repo: https://github.com/appleboy/ssh-action?tab=readme-ov-file

Not terribly relevant if that's not the version you're using.

What do you mean? So you mean to say the latest version does not support the "protocol" input, but still has it in readme on how to use..

I don't know how else to put it. "protocol is one of inputs on this version" - no, it's not.

Thanks for pointing that out, my mistake for blindly believing and not checking myself...

AS @jonrsharpe pointed out protocol input is not in v1.0.3 so I put appleboy/ssh-action@master and it solved my issues.
